# Filter pandas dataframe columns based on value for columns in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df defined as below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["A"] = ['True','True','True','True','True']
df["B"] = ['True','False','True','False','True']
df["C"] = ['False','True','False','True','False']
df["D"] = ['True','True','False','False','False']
df["E"] = ['False','True','True','False','True']
df["F"] = ['HI','HI','HI','HI','HI']
```

```
>> df

      A      B      C      D      E   F
0  True   True  False   True  False  HI
1  True  False   True   True   True  HI
2  True   True  False  False   True  HI
3  True  False   True  False  False  HI
4  True   True  False  False   True  HI
```

and a list

```
lst = ["A","C"]
```

I would like to filter the rows in df based on the values being `'True'` for the columns in `lst`.
That is, I would like to get my resultant dataframe as :

```
      A      B     C      D      E   F
1  True  False  True   True   True  HI
3  True  False  True  False  False  HI
```

Instead of looping through the column names from the list and filtering it, is there any better solution for this?

Comment: +1 for the easy way of getting your dataframe. Most question put in their dataframe and if I want to help I need to define every column on my own.

Comment: @MisterNox you can use `pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')`

Comment: That's a good one. I did not know this. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: it will be `True` `False` instead of `'True'` `'False'` in df

Answer (score 5):

Use `DatFrame.all` over the column axis (`axis=1`):

```
df[df[lst].all(axis=1)]

      A      B     C      D      E   F
1  True  False  True   True   True  HI
3  True  False  True  False  False  HI
```

---

Details:

We get the columns in scope with `df[lst]`, then we use `all` to check which rows have "all"  as `True`:

```
df[lst].all(axis=1)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: nice one, my mind went straight to `df[df[lst].sum(1).eq(len(lst))]` but this is more idiomatic and pythonic

Comment: @Erfan, thanks for the answer. I have a doubt. What if I need to compare each value with a string rather than checking whether it is True/False?

Comment: Please edit your input data in your question to showcase the problem, because right now it matches your expected output.

Comment: @Erfan, I have edited the input data in the question, can you please help me?